# Python 3 setting ping to variable returns 0

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

```
import os

host = "www.yahoo.com"
test = os.system("ping -c 10 " + host + " | tail -1| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2")

print(test)

def check_ping():
    hostname = "www.google.com"

    response = os.system("ping -c 10 " + hostname + " | tail -1| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2")

    print(int(response))
    if response > 0:
        print("boo")
        print("Network Active. Average response time is: " + str(response))

    else:
        print("Network Error: No connection to destination")
check_ping()
```

## setting it as a float

[root@web python3]# python3 testNet.py

8.113

0.0

Network Error: No connection to destination

## added another url and set it as an int

[root@web python3]# python3 testNet.py

44.992

0

11.377

0

Network Error: No connection to destination

Why is it that when you ping it sets it to zero when you try to do anything with it??
The other prints are just to see how its passing through

Comment: Did you bother reading the doc ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is spelled in all letters in the documentation.

Comment: Apparently i missed that part with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.system` will return the value of the process, `0` if it had no error. You need to use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to get the `stdout` from your command.

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["ping -c 10 " + "www.google.com" + " | tail -1| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2"])
```